# What happens outside of transaction blocks?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

The [JOOQ Transaction Management](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.12/manual/sql-execution/transaction-management/) documentation is a bit light on details. Please help me understand the difference between the following 4 cases:

```
DSLContext outer = DSL.using(jdbcConnection, SQLDialect.POSTGRES);

// case 1
outer.insertInto(someTable).set(...).execute();

outer.transaction(transactional ->
{
    DSLContext inner = DSL.using(transactional);

    // case 2
    outer.insertInto(someTable).set(...).execute();

    // case 3
    inner.insertInto(someTable).set(...).execute();

    inner.transaction(transactional2 ->
    {
      DSLContext inner2 = DSL.using(transactional2);

      // case 4
      inner2.insertInto(someTable).set(...).execute();
    }
});
```

My guess is that:

- Case 1 runs against an auto-commit transaction.
- Case 2 is identical to case 1 even though it is inside a `TransactionalRunnable` block because it doesn't use `transactional`.
- Case 3 runs against a transaction that does not auto-commit and is independent of the transaction(s) used by case 1 or 2.
- Case 4 runs against a transaction that does not auto-commit and is nested inside the transaction used by case 3.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, jOOQ doesn't manage your transactions, or even care about your transactions. So:

- Case 1 runs with whatever transaction management you specified outside of jOOQ, including e.g. JDBC's autocommit flag, which may or may not be turned on by default. If you don't have any external transaction management (e.g. Spring), then you're probably right, as most drivers default to autocommit = true.
- Case 2 sets your JDBC autocommit flag to `false` for the execution of the lambda receiving the `transactional` argument, and sets it back to what it was before the lambda. Since both your `outer` and your `transactional` ultimately operate on the same `jdbcConnection`, case 2 is *not* the same as case 1. It will "by accident" also run in the same jOOQ-managed transaction. If you had passed a `DataSource` to `outer`, then it would be possible to achieve the behaviour you've described (see below).
- Case 3 is independent of the transaction in case 1, but will run in the same transaction "by accident" as case 2.
- Case 4 is indeed a nested transaction of the transaction defined by `transactional`

I can see how case 2 seems confusing from your code example, but it does make sense if you think about how jOOQ's `TransactionProvider` and `ConnectionProvider` SPIs interact:

- `ConnectionProvider` provides jOOQ with a JDBC connection for a single query execution.

  - If you pass jOOQ a `Connection`, then that is wrapped in [`DefaultConnectionProvider`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DefaultConnectionProvider.html), which always produces the same JDBC `Connection` again. There's no way for jOOQ in your case 2 to produce a new JDBC `Connection` that is independent of your currently running transaction, because in JDBC, a `Connection` can only have a single transaction at a time.
  - If you pass jOOQ a `DataSource`, then that is wrapped in [`DataSourceConnectionProvider`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DataSourceConnectionProvider.html). Now, the `DataSource` may choose to provide jOOQ with a new JDBC `Connection` depending on whether there is already a transaction going on, or not. In this case, it would be possible to achieve your case 2 with an appropriate `TransactionProvider`
- `TransactionProvider` manages the transaction lifecycle whenever you call one of jOOQ's various `DSLContext::transaction` methods. It makes sure that the `DSLContext` argument of your lambda will no longer query your `ConnectionProvider` for connections, but stores it internally and makes sure you will keep using the JDBC `Connection` that has your transaction attached to it. This mechanism also allows for nesting transactions as in your case 4.

Put differently, if you would use Spring's `@Transactional` annotations in most places, but somehow managed to access the "raw" JDBC `Connection` that was initialised somewhere outside of a Spring `@Transactional` context, then you would have the same effect. You would also "accidentally" inherit the `@Transactional` context.

Comment: To clarify, case 3 is intended to run in the transaction created by `outer.transaction()`. Is that actually the case?

Comment: @Gili: Yes, that is the case.